# How can I diff my current working version of a file with a previous version of the file in git

Tags: git

I made changes to my file. I see the diff of what I made with HEAD by using 'git diff'.

How can I see the diff of my working file with the version of the file in a previous commit (assume I know the SHA).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To see the diff of the working file with the version of the file in a previous commit:

```
git diff -c <SHA1> <pathspec>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a diff with a prior version using one of the many different types of [revision parameters](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions).

```
git diff HEAD@{yesterday} <path>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this form of the `git diff` command:

```
git diff [<commit>] [--] [<path>...]
```

Where:

- `commit` can be an SHA1, branch, tag, and you can use the usual modifiers like `^^^` and `~3` to refer to previous commits relative to SHA1/branch/tag
- The `--` is optional: only necessary when the path conflicts with a branch name
- `path` is of course the path to the file you want to diff

`git diff` is very powerful, read more about it in `git diff --help`